# Android activity "implements" cannot resolve the symbol of a class method?

Tags: java, android

```
public class RotationGestureDetector {

    public interface OnRotationGestureListener {
        public void OnRotation(RotationGestureDetector rotationDetector);
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CameraHostProvider, RotationGestureDetector.onRotationGestureListener {

@Override
    public void OnRotation(RotationGestureDetector rotationDetector) {
        float angle = rotationDetector.getAngle();
        Log.d("RotationGestureDetector", "Rotation: " + Float.toString(angle));
    }

}
```

Then in  RotationGestureDetector.onRotationGestureListener it cannot resolve onRotationGestureListener. I feel like there is something tricky about the interface that Im not understanding but I really feel that this method is clearly defined here.

My understanding is that the interface OnRotationGestureListener sets up an interface with an object rotationDetector that has all of the methods defined in the RotationGestureDetector class available to it such as getAngle(). But Im not sure why this means that you cannot access the interface from the class in the first place.

Any suggestions especially with a clear explanation for why interfaces don't work this way would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo. Instead of

```
RotationGestureDetector.onRotationGestureListener
```

you need

```
RotationGestureDetector.OnRotationGestureListener
                        ^
                        |
                        Note case change
```